# Rails @url instance variable why does it not work as a normal instance variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have tried to use an instance variable named `@url`

Controller: `@url = "asdasdsa"`

But when I call it in view: `<%= @url %>` it was empty....

I did change the name to `@url_test` and it worked. Just wondering why did it not work with  @url ? Is the name protected or what?

Comment: What is your rails version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a known issue in rails 3.0.x:

See this github issue: [Views are losing the @url instance variable.](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2447)

> spastorino commented a year ago
>   Don't remember why but @url is an internal ivar in 3.0 AP, that's the thing.

It should be fixed with Rails 3.1.0. As a workaround don't call your instance variable `@url` or upgrade your app.

Answer (score 0):

`url` is a reserved word in Rails. You can see a more complete list (though maybe not up-to-date) at [this](http://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/) site.

Comment: That site is not up to date. Most the entries are updated over 3 years ago. And the list only contains `Url` there not the `@url`.